# Can't figure out basic CSS

Tags: css

So I have few buttons that are arranged in this fashion:

```
<button>Home</button>
<button>Blog</button>
<button>Forums</button>
<button>Contact Us</button>
```

I want to have a "selected" class or ID that changes the background of the selected button. 
I tried doing this:

```
button > .selected {
    background: red !important;
}
```

And changed button in HTML to this:

```
<button class="selected">Home</button>
```

It didn't do anything at all, button background stayed the same color. I also tried using ID instead of class to no avail.

How can I solve this task easily?

Comment: *"A `button` element with the class `selected`"* is expressed by `button.selected`. `>` does something you don't want at all.

Comment: This is really CSS basics. If you'd google it, you found the answer in like 5 seconds.

Comment: While I do understand that this question could have been solved with more intensive research, I think it should not voted down to oblivion, as it is technically complete and clear.

Comment: @NicoO [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Turnip thanks for the link, this article seems to be a missing part in my handling of questions here. I will see into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
button.selected {
    background: red !important;
}
```

For a button **with** a class (Make sure there's no space between them, or you will be selecting child elements)

You should also be able to remove the `!important` unless there's actually a good reason to keep it. Since the selector including a class is more specific than a standard selector, it will overwrite the background colour without the use of `!important`.

The `>` symbol means a direct child of an element.

Here's a few beginers resources for leaning about CSS selectors:

- https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/
- https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Why do you suggest to keep the `!important`?

Comment: @NicoO I wouldn't use it personally, but I was only correcting the selector, I was assuming there's more reasoning behind it than is shown in the question.

Answer (score -1):

try these code, it will work

```
button{
    background:green;
}

button.selected {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: How does this help with the question?

Comment: can you repeat the question ?

Comment: Try explaining your code.

Answer (score -1):

```css
button:active,button:focus {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Home</button>
<button>Blog</button>
<button>Forums</button>
<button>Contact Us</button>
```

Comment: Try also giving an explanation with your code.